# Yii2 : Show image from Folder Common

Tags: image, yii2

I have a picture in folder common that i want to show in view, but it doesn't shown.

My code is :

```
<img src="<?= Yii::$app->request->baseUrl . '/common/web/img/ava.jpg' ?>" class=" img-responsive" >
```

It's generated to be `<img src="/simdsm/common/web/ava.jpg" class=" img-responsive">` but the image does not appear.

How to fix it?

Comment: Have you found any solution, If it is please share with me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of using advanced application template, images should be placed in these web accessible folders - `frontend/web` or `backend/web`.

Also usually I create alias from `frontend/web/images` to `backend/web/images` to display images in backend from frontend.

What you mentioned is not web accessible directory.

Alternative way to publish images from such directory will be creating asset bundle for that folder, that way images will be copied in `frontend/web/assets` for example. You can read more about asset bundles in [official docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html).

Comment: how to create alias from `frontend/web/images` to `backend/web/images` ? thanks

Comment: Run `ln -s ../../frontend/web/images images` from `backend/web` folder

Comment: Forgot to mention - it's better to delete destination folder (`backend/web/images`) before doing that.

Comment: oke thanks, i've tried other way, but i appreciated you answer :)

Comment: @ariyandi You can post the other solution that worked for you as answer so the others can know too.

Comment: @arogachev I didn't understand how to publish folder. Could you try to explain again

Answer (score 5):

Since no one actually posted an example of using assets to access files saved in a backend-folder or the other way around, it's quite simple:

Let's say you are working with the yii advanced template and you have a `backup/web/uploads/` folder in which you save images uploaded via your backend. Now you'd like to display those images on your frontend. Since the Frontend-App and the Backend-App are two seperate Applications, they don't know of each other.

You create a new asset in your `frontend/assets/`, let's call it **BackendAsset.php**:

```
<?php

   namespace frontend\assets;
   use yii\web\AssetBundle;

   class BackendAsset extends AssetBundle {
      public $sourcePath = '@backend/web/uploads';
   }
```

where `$sourcePath` is the backend-folder (source) you'd like to access on the frontend. The @backend alias is [predefined in the advanced template](https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-path-aliases), so we'll use it.

Now in our view we can simply use the BackendAsset:

```
<?php

    use frontend\assets\BackendAsset;
    $backend = BackendAsset::register($this);

?>
```

and now we can easily display a file, let's say `backend/web/uploads/somefile.jpg`:

```
<img src="<?= $backend->baseUrl . '/somefile.jpg' ?>" >
```

**NOTE**: Using the asset in this way **copies all the files** from the `backend/web/uploads` to an asset folder in the frontend. To prevent that, you can tell your application **not to copy** the files, but **to link to them** (creating SymLinks) instead, using `linkAssets` ([yii2 docu](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-assetmanager#$linkAssets-detail)):

In your app configuration (in this case `frontend/config/main.php`), set the `linkAssets` parameter to **TRUE**:

```
'components' => [
    'assetManager' => [
        'linkAssets' => true,
        ]
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do it easily by simple step of below
In common/config/params-local.php

```
Yii::setAlias('@imageurl', 'http://localhost/project_name/backend/web/');
```

in above example i have my image under backend/web/images/product_images

In frontend, i am getting like,

```
<img src="<?php echo Yii ::getAlias('@imageurl'); ?>/images/product_images/<?= $product['image']?>" alt=" " class="img-responsive" />
```

it's simply working for me...