# Yii2-advanced, how to display images from backend in frontend

Tags: php, image, frontend, backend

I have my images in /backend/web/uploads.
Now I would like to show them in /frontend/views/site/index

So in index view I'm trying to show them like this:

```
 $planet = Planet::find()->all();
foreach($planet AS $pl=> $p){
    echo Html::img('/backend/web/'.($p->path));
}
```

in $p->path -  uploads/123.jpg

But this path is not valid, how can I display images from 
/backend/web/uploads in /frontend/views/site/index ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Yii2 : Show image from Folder Common](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31331574/yii2-show-image-from-folder-common)

Answer (score 3):

It's already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31331574/yii2-show-image-from-folder-common/31331809#31331809).

There are two main options to achieve that.

**1)** You can create alias from `frontend/web/images` to `backend/web/images` to display images in backend from frontend.

Run `ln -s ../../frontend/web/images images` from `backend/web` folder. It's better to delete destination folder (`backend/web/images`) before doing that.

**2)** Alternative way to publish images from such directory will be creating asset bundle for that folder, that way images will be copied in `frontend/web/assets` for example. You can read more about asset bundles in [official docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html).

Answer (score 0):

Go to your `frontend/config` and add:

```
'components' => [
    // You can name it whatever you want as it is custom
    'urlManagerBackend' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\urlManager',
        'baseUrl' => 'yourbackendend/absolutepath/uploads/',
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
    ],
],
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
Html::img(Yii::$app->urlManagerBackend->baseUrl.'/uploads/your_img.png');
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it by creating of ONE directory for backend images and frontend images:

In my common/config/bootstrap.php:

```
Yii::setAlias('@root', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)));
```

In my common/config/main.php:

```
'modules' => [
      'yii2images' => [
         'class' => 'rico\yii2images\Module',
         //be sure, that permissions ok
         //if you cant avoid permission errors you have to create "images" folder in web root manually and set 777 permissions
         'imagesStorePath' => '@root/upload/store', //path to origin images
         'imagesCachePath' => '@root/upload/cache', //path to resized copies
         'graphicsLibrary' => 'GD', //but really its better to use 'Imagick'
         'placeHolderPath' => '@root/upload/store/no-image.png', // if you want to get placeholder when image not exists, string will be processed by Yii::getAlias
         'imageCompressionQuality' => 85, // Optional. Default value is 85.
      ],
]
```

And created the 'imagesStorePath' and the 'imagesCachePath' in the root project directory.