# yii2 PendalF89/yii2-filemanager uploading to folder shared by frontend & backend

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am trying to implement [yii2 PendalF89/yii2-filemanager](https://github.com/PendalF89/yii2-filemanager) within the backend of my application with the following in my config:

```
        'routes' => [
            // Base absolute path to web directory
            'baseUrl' => '',
            // Base web directory url
            'basePath' => '../',
            // Path for uploaded files in web directory
            'uploadPath' => 'uploads',
        ],
```

The above configuration uploads the files to the correct directory however they are not being displayed within the file manager which I think is due to the thumbnail URL being /backend/uploads rather than just /uploads

After uploading an image I get the following message:

```
{"files":[{"url":"/uploads/2016/01/educationcentre.jpg","thumbnailUrl":"/backend/uploads/2016/01/educationcentre-128x128.jpg","name":"educationcentre.jpg","type":"image/jpeg","size":223742,"deleteUrl":"/backend/filemanager/file/delete?id=12","deleteType":"POST"}]}
```

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31331574/yii2-show-image-from-folder-common/31331809#31331809) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31358708/yii2-advanced-how-to-display-images-from-backend-in-frontend/31374981#31374981) answers.

Comment: @arogachev thanks from them however I had read them and have implemented some of the answers however the problem I think is possible due to the extension I am using so it was more specific to that than a general yii2 image upload problem.