# Yii2 - Access a folder in root folder?

Tags: php, yii2, alias

I need to access images in the upload folder inside root folder.
I created a alias and tried this:

**root**

```
-backend
-common
-frontend
-uploads
 ...
```

**common/config/bootstrap.php**

```
Yii::setAlias('@uploads', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/uploads');
```

**view.php**

```
<?= Html::img(Yii::getAlias('@uploads') . '/party/IMG_900.jpg'); ?>
```

But the image does not load.

Comment: For uploading image you have to use document root path but while display image use http path like Yii::$app->request->baseUrl

Comment: you are using `advance-app` and you need to place your images in the web accessible directory which is `frontend/web` or `backend/web` as your stating script resides in these 2 directories you should place your uploads folder inside one of these folders where ever you want to access them

Comment: @Dipti Yii::$app->request->baseUrl  returns "/root/frontend/web" i need access "/root/uploads/"

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam why can't I use a common uploads?

Comment: by saying **common** i assume you need to access it from `frontend` and `backend` apps if i am not wrong, and you can access the `frontend/web` by adding a `urlManagerFrontend` component in the `backend/config/main.php` and you can access the frontend uploads folder from there, see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31331574/yii2-show-image-from-folder-common/31331809#31331809

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam i need access images in folder "uploads" see my first post and look the directory, i don't explain correctly? sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `src` attribute of the `img` tag is relative to the address of the web root. You should write it as `/uploads/party/IMG_900.jpg`, then create a soft link in your `frontend/web` (or `backend/web`) directory and point to the `/root/uploads` directory.

Directory structure example:

```
root
 - backend
  - web
   - uploads -> ../../uploads
 - frontend
  - web
   - uploads -> ../../uploads
 - common
 - uploads
```

in view.php

```
<?= Html::img('/uploads/party/IMG_900.jpg'); ?>
```

Comment: It looks fine, but how do I create this soft link? else if u simply do this `<?= Html::img('/root/uploads/party/IMG_900.jpg'); ?>` solves my problem, is that correct?

Comment: @Tiago I am using linux and can create a soft link. If you use windows system, you should be able to do it with "shortcuts". Create a "shortcut" for the `/root/uploads` folder in your `frontend/web` (or `backend/web`) directory

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using a filesystem path as your image source - `Yii::setAlias` will return something like `/root/uploads` but `Html::img` expects a URL. If you look in your browser dev tools you'll probably see a 404 error for `/root/uploads/party/IMG_900.jpg` or something like that.

Comment: Yes, I'm using this on the homepage and before I was using the path this way "'../../../' . 'uploads/party/IMG_900.jpg/'" and it works if I access the link in the browser like "app/frontend/web/site/index" but if I access this path "app/frontend/web "no longer works

Comment: I don't understand - what is the `src` attribute of the `img` tag coming through as?

Comment: the src is "C:\xampp\htdocs\rootFolder/uploads/party/IMG_900.jpg" @tschumann